# Resolving a leak from the jQuery source

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I am not part of the jQuery team but [this leak](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8545) caught my eye. The test case is simple, nothing fancy is happening, and yet it seems that finding the cause of the leak is a real challenge.

I would like to attempt to fix the leak, but have no idea how to go about it. What tools/techniques/approaches should I use?

[I know this question is a little vague, but my ultimate aim is very precise: *fix that damn leak*.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the uncompressed source of jQuery: [1.6.4](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js) ([Older versions](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)). After knowning the real JavaScript code (behind the scenes), you can start constructing a test case.

The first step is to isolate the issue. Disable parts of the function (at a local, modified version of your jQuery file). Test the new function under different conditions, to make sure that the applied change made a difference. *The issue is reported at IE 6, 7, and 8. Confirm this report by checking it across multiple browsers.*

When you've found the cause, try to create a fix: Start writing a basic solution, which (partially) implement the feature. Repeat the cycle to check whether the patch is behaving as expected.

After spending several hours, you might have created a fix for the issue. Before celebrating this, compare the effectiveness of the original, and patched function at relevant test cases. Don't be afraid of asking help from others.